# How to solve Warning: React does not recognize the X prop on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, producer-consumer

I'm using a thing called [react-firebase-js](https://react-firebase-js.com) to handle firebase auth, but my understanding of react and of the provider-consumer idea is limited.

I started with a built a very big JSX thing all at the top level, and that works without warnings.  But when I try to break it into components, I got the warning shown in the title and a few others.

This works without warning...

```
// in App.js component

  render() {
    return (
        <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <FirebaseAuthConsumer>
                {({ isSignedIn, user, providerId }) => {
                    if (isSignedIn) {
                        return (
                           // ui for signed in user
                        );  
                    } else {
                        if (this.state.confirmationResult) {
                            return (
                                // ui to get a phone number sign in
                            );
                        } else {                  
                            return (
                                // ui to verify sms code that was sent
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }}
            </FirebaseAuthConsumer>
        </header>
    );
  }
```

But this, better design, I thought, generates errors/warnings...

```
// in App.js component
render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
      <FirebaseAuthProvider {...config} firebase={firebase}>
        <div className="App">
          <IfFirebaseAuthed>
            <p>You're authed buddy</p>
            <RaisedButton label="Sign Out" onClick={this.signOutClick} />
          </IfFirebaseAuthed>
          <IfFirebaseUnAuthed>
              <Authenticater />  // <-- this is the new component
        </IfFirebaseUnAuthed>
        </div>
      </FirebaseAuthProvider>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }

// in my brand new Authenticator component...

  render() {
    return (
        <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <FirebaseAuthConsumer>
                {({ isSignedIn, user, providerId }) => {
                    if (isSignedIn) {
                        return (
                        <div>
                            <pre style={{ height: 300, overflow: "auto" }}>
                            {JSON.stringify({ isSignedIn, user, providerId }, null, 2)}
                            </pre>
                        </div>
                        );  
                    } else {
                        if (this.state.confirmationResult) {
                            return (
                                // ui to get a phone number sign in
                            );
                        } else {                  
                            return (
                                // ui to verify an sms code that was sent
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }}
            </FirebaseAuthConsumer>
        </header>
    );
  }
```

The errors/warnings look like this...

> [Error] Warning: React does not recognize the `isSignedIn` prop on a
>   DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a
>   custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `issignedin` instead. If you
>   accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM
>   element.
>
> [Error] Warning: React does not recognize the `providerId` prop on a
>   DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a
>   custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `providerid` instead. If you
>   accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM
>   element.
>
> [Error] Error: Unable to load external reCAPTCHA dependencies!
>     (anonymous function) (0.chunk.js:1216) [Error] Error: The error you
>   provided does not contain a stack trace.

Am I misunderstanding how to use provider-consumers, or is there an error in the react-firebase code, or am I doing some other thing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: delete `{JSON.stringify({ isSignedIn, user, providerId }, null, 2)}` and check if the error is still showing up

Comment: @evgenifotia - thanks.  tried it and got the same errors.

Comment: How `FirebaseAuthProvider` is implemented?

Comment: Please add FirebaseAuthProvider code

Comment: You get the error because you put `isSignedIn` and `providerId` on one of DOM elements. Like this: `<h3 isSignedIn={...}>stuff</h3>`. This is not valid in react. Search your code with all the cases where you use the `isSignedIn` and `providerId` and make sure they are not directly on a HTML element. It needs to be a react component.
You can see it in action here https://codesandbox.io/s/o4kn2vqj4q

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Presumably, this line must be the culprit:

```
<FirebaseAuthProvider {...config} firebase={firebase}>
```

Your `config` object currently holds fields `isSignedIn` and `providerId`, and you must be sending those down to children components, and ultimately to a DOM element. Try removing those fields from the object before you send them down:

```
const { providerId, isSignedIn, ...authProviderConfig } = config
```

That way, your object `authProviderConfig` will not hold the `providerId` or `isSignedIn` attributes.

Even better, you can rebuild the configuration object explicitly to avoid any further confusion:

```
const authProviderConfig = { /* The fields from config FirebaseAuthProvider actually needs */ }
```

You should also check your `FirebaseAuthProvider` component to see how it's using those props, and avoid spreading them down to DOM elements.

Related documentation: https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html

Answer (score 16):

Adding $ to the prop name fixed it for me.

.tsx file:

```
<Wrapper $offset={isOffset}>
```

And on the .style.tsx file:

```
height: ${({ $offset }) => ($offset ? 'calc(100% + 20px)' : '100%')};
```

Comment: Same for me. Just in case, here is the documentation for that: https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props

Comment: This is a breaking change when updating to styled-components 6+

Answer (score 11):

### You passed a prop on a component that it is not valid

For example, this will trigger the warning:

```
<Component someUnknownProp='random-text' />
```

In order to get rid of the warning you should find out where that warning is coming from.

The stack trace should give you a hint.

Answer (score 8):

### Check your custom props

In my case, I created a reusable hide component. (Initially, it mounts a button with text masked(`******`) on clicking this button the key( API key ) will be revealed which is a CopyToClipboard component )

```
const [hide, setHide] = useState(true);
```

If `hide` is `true`, I am rendering a Button ( spreading all the props )

```
<Button onClick={() => setHide(false)} {...props}>
     ******
</Button>
```

When this button is Clicked `hide` is false and I am rendering a CopyToClipboard component.

```
<CopyToClipboard
   {...props}
>
  {value}
</CopyToClipboard>
```

### The Problem

1. In the above scenario, I am spreading `{...props}` to both Button and CopyToClipboard components.
2. But some props of CopyToClipboard are not compatible with that of Button's.

### Fix

1. So at the top of the component destructure the props that are specific to a component (here CopyToClipboard).
2. Now safely spread the rest of the props to both the components and pass the new prop separately ( to CopyToClipboard component )

```
const {onCopy, ...restProps} = props
```

```
<Button onClick={() => setHide(false)} {...restProps}>
     ******
</Button>
```

```
<CopyToClipboard
   onCopy={onCopy}
   {...restProps}
>
  {value}
</CopyToClipboard>
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was getting this error when using the IfFirebaseAuthed component from react-firebase.

You must make sure that you return a function inside of this component.

I changed this:

```
<IfFirebaseAuthed>
  ... My authenticated code here ...
</IfFirebaseAuthed>
```

To this:

```
<IfFirebaseAuthed>
 {() => (
    ... My authenticated code here ...
 )}
</IfFirebaseAuthed>
```

And this issue went away.