# React & Material UI Warning: "React does not recognize the `ATTRIBUTE` prop on a DOM element." I never declared ATTRIBUTE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, components

I have made a Horizontal Grid List in React with Material UI, but the GridListTile component is throwing 4 warnings (below) about attribute being on the `<li>`

> in li (created by ForwardRef(GridListTile))

the errors are regarding the Attributes: `disableElevation`, `disableFocusRipple`, `disableRipple`, `fullWidth`. all of which i have used elsewhere in the app, but not anywhere in this file or the children components.

**Errors:**
[error in console, everything is the same in the other 3 attributes, including code line numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rq2M.png)

```
Warning: React does not recognize the `disableElevation` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `disableelevation` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
in li (created by ForwardRef(GridListTile))
in ForwardRef(GridListTile) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(GridListTile)))
in WithStyles(ForwardRef(GridListTile)) (at Feed.js:202)
in div (created by ForwardRef(ButtonGroup))
in ForwardRef(ButtonGroup) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(ButtonGroup)))
in WithStyles(ForwardRef(ButtonGroup)) (at Feed.js:200)
in ul (created by ForwardRef(GridList))
in ForwardRef(GridList) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(GridList)))
in WithStyles(ForwardRef(GridList)) (at Feed.js:199)
in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at Feed.js:198)
in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at Feed.js:197)
in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at Feed.js:196)
in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at Feed.js:221)
in div (created by ForwardRef(Container))
in ForwardRef(Container) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Container)))
in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Container)) (at Feed.js:220)
in Feed (created by Context.Consumer)
in Route (at Routes.js:69)
in Switch (at Routes.js:61)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (at Routes.js:60)
in ThemeProvider (at Routes.js:59)
in Routes (at src/index.js:5)
```

here is the code for the GridList section

```
const feedButtons = () => {
return (
  <Grid item style={{ marginBottom: "0.25rem" }}>
    <Grid container direction="row" justify="center" alignItems="center">
      <Grid item className={classes.horizList}>
        <GridList className={classes.gridList} cols={2.5}>   //this is line #199 in the code
          <ButtonGroup variant="text" aria-label="show fed item selection">
            {typesArray.map((tile, i) => (
              <GridListTile key={tile.label}>
                <Button
                  color="secondary"
                  onClick={() => setShow(tile.source)}
                >
                  {tile.label}
                </Button>
              </GridListTile>
            ))}
          </ButtonGroup>
        </GridList>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
);};
```

this is the return section of the component:

```
  return (
<Container disableGutters>
  <Grid
    container
    direction="column"
    justify="flex-start"
    alignItems="center"
  >
    {feedButtons()}
    {showItems()}
    {showError()}
  </Grid>
</Container>
```

);

It is all just a normal level React component besides the GridTile & i don't know how go and change the inner workings of the GridTile component as is sort of suggested in this similar problem/answer:
[stackoverflow similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54468535/how-to-solve-warning-react-does-not-recognize-the-x-prop-on-a-dom-element)

How do i get these warnings to go away, hopefully by fixing the issue, or via something else?

Comment: This is because you have `GridListTile` as a child of `ButtonGroup`. `ButtonGroup` [uses cloneElement to modify the props of its children](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.3/packages/material-ui/src/ButtonGroup/ButtonGroup.js#L223) which it is assuming are `Button` elements.

Comment: That link makes it clear, thank you. I was using the ButtonGroup like that as it made the styling look good, but it guess it is not a good way to do things. I'll get rid of the ButtonGroup and stick with just a GridList>GridListTile>Button setup. Thanks for helping, it cleared up my confusion & helped resolve my issue.

Comment: This should be posted in an answer so it could be accepted. I had the exact same problem with `Tabs` component, containing `Tab` elements and another DOM element, which was giving me errors since props were cloned and passed to this element. Taking it out of the `Tabs` element solved the issue!